# Keep first regex match and discard others

Tags: regex, powershell

Yep another regex question... I am using PowerShell to extract a simple number from a filename when looping through a folder like so:

```
# sample string "ABCD - (123) Sample Text Here"

Get-ChildItem $processingFolder -filter *.xls | Where-Object {
    $name = $_.Name
    $pattern = '(\d{2,3})'
    $metric = ([regex]$pattern).Matches($name) | { $_.Groups[1].Value }
}
```

All I am looking for is the number surrounded by brackets. This is successful, but it appears the $_.Name actually grabs more than just the name of the file, and the regex ends up picking up some other bits I don't want.

I understand why, as it's going through each regex match as an object and taking the value out of each and putting in $metric. I need some help editing the code so it only bothers with the first object.

I would just use -match etc if I wasn't bothered with the actual contents of the match, but it needs to be kept.

Comment: In your sample you do not include in your question (which is integral for regex questions.). Are you trying to match the numbers in brackets at the beginning of the string? You can make that so you wont have multiple matches.

Comment: I don't want the brackets around the number, just the number. If I picked the brackets up too it would probably stop the other bits being picked up, I'm not sure. I've now got the tricky task of integrating the array of objects you provided earlier in to this loop of files! This question is around extracting the labels.

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to say. What are you doing with the number once you have it.

Comment: It will be put in the custom object you designed earlier as Details[0] if that makes sense. I already have the other two numbers being extracted from their source [1] and [2] to then make up my set of 3 desired numbers. I just need to piece all the bits together now. Expect another question shortly when it all falls over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a cmdlet call before `$_.Groups[1].Value` which should be `ForEach-Object` but that is a minor thing. We need to make a small improvement on your regex pattern as well to account for the brackets but not include them in the return.

```
$processingFolder = "C:\temp"
$pattern = '\((\d+)\)'
Get-ChildItem $processingFolder -filter "*.xls" | ForEach-Object{
    $details = ""
    if($_.Name -match $pattern){$details = $matches[1]}
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Details -Value $details -PassThru
} | select name, details
```

This will loop all the files and try and match numbers in brackets. If there is more than one match it should only take the first one. We use a capture group in order to ignore the brackets in the results. Next we use Add-Member to make a new property called `Details` which will contain the matched value.

Currently this will return all files in the `$processingFolder` but a simple `Where-Object{$_.Details}` would return just the ones that have the property populated. If you have other properties that you need to make you can chain the `Add-Member`s together. Just don't forget the `-passthru`.

You could also just make your own new object if you need to go that route with multiple custom parameters. It certainly would be more terse. That [last question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33016137/how-can-i-return-the-position-a-nested-array-is-in-from-the-value-of-the-first/33017054#33017054) has an example of that.

Comment: I come back from a meeting and it's been written for me! Thanks Matt, this has given me a lot to digest and work with.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research in to the data being returned itself (System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection) I found the Item method, so called that on $metric like so:

```
$name = '(111) 123 456 789 Name of Report Here 123'
$pattern = '(\d{2,3})'
$metric = ([regex]$pattern).Matches($name)
Write-Host $metric.Item(1)
```

Whilst probably not the best approach, it returns what I'm expecting for now.